# Ошибка в условии if else

Tags: android, kotlin

Решаю следующую задачку, но какое то условие явно не проходит, не могу смекнуть какое, вроде всё описал

> Нa шахматной доске стоят черный король и две белые ладьи (ладья бьет
>   по горизонтали и вертикали). Определить, не находится ли король под
>   боем, а если есть угроза, то от кого именно. Вернуть 0, если угрозы
>   нет, 1, если угроза только от первой ладьи, 2, если только от второй
>   ладьи, и 3, если угроза от обеих ладей. Считать, что ладьи не могут
>   загораживать друг друга

Код задачки:

```
fun whichRookThreatens(kingX: Int, kingY: Int,
                       rookX1: Int, rookY1: Int,
                       rookX2: Int, rookY2: Int): Int {
    return if ((kingX == rookX1) || (kingY == rookY1)) 1 //угроза от первой ладьи
    else if ((kingX != rookX1) && (kingY != rookY1) && (kingX != rookX2) && (kingY != rookY2)) 0 //угрозы нет
    else if ((kingX == rookX2) || (kingY == rookY2)) 2 //угроза от второй ладьи
    else if ((kingX == rookX1) || (kingY == rookY1) && (kingX == rookX2) || (kingY == rookY2)) 3 //угроза от обеих ладей
    else 5
}
```

Падает тест на последнем условии:

```
@Test
fun whichRookThreatens() {
    assertEquals(0, whichRookThreatens(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
    assertEquals(1, whichRookThreatens(5, 3, 7, 3, 4, 8))
    assertEquals(2, whichRookThreatens(6, 8, 8, 6, 6, 3))
    assertEquals(3, whichRookThreatens(3, 7, 8, 7, 3, 5))
}
```

Comment: Ну решение по факту неверно - если стрельнёт первое условие, остальные elseif не проверятся, и шах от второй ладьи не отловится, к примеру... А вообще сделай проще, на тернарках, типа `return ((kingX == rookX1) || (kingY == rookY1))?1:0 + ((kingX == rookX2) || (kingY == rookY2))?2:0`.

Comment: @Akina в Kotlin нет тернарного оператора

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon Ну сложить два отдельных `if`... не суть.

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon в kotlin само [условие if возвращает результат проверки](http://kotlin.ohandroid.com/919.html), поэтому тернарный оператор и не нужен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша функция никогда не проверяет угрозу от двух ладей сразу, потому что как только она находит угрозу от одной их них, то сразу возвращает от какой конкретно, поэтому сначала нужно проверить на угрозу от обеих ладей, и || нужно обернуть в скобки при этой проверке, т.к. приоритет меньше, чем у &&

```
fun whichRookThreatens(kingX: Int, kingY: Int,
                       rookX1: Int, rookY1: Int,
                       rookX2: Int, rookY2: Int): Int {
    return if ((kingX == rookX1 || kingY == rookY1) && (kingX == rookX2 || kingY == rookY2)) 3 //угроза от обеих ладей
    else if (kingX == rookX2 || kingY == rookY2) 2 //угроза от второй ладьи
    else if (kingX == rookX1 || kingY == rookY1) 1 //угроза от первой ладьи
    else 0 //угрозы нет
}
```

Comment: Комментарий про последовательность то что нужно, остальное всё сложилось в картину ;)